# jQuery selector that is syntactically correct only brings up empty object

Tags: jquery, selector

Good evening everyone. A jQuery selector that is correct only returns an empty object. The variables are all defined and have values (I console.log them) but I always get an empty object. What have I missed?

Here comes the code in question. Posting all code would be superfluous.

```js
// reihe is 0, 1, or 2
var mycell = $('span:nth-child(' + reihe + ')');
```

The above selector returns this in the console:

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: {…} }
```

The HTML in question would be...

```
<span align="center" id="r1">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r2">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r3">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
```

And yes, jQuery is loaded of course.

Comment: um, what is the value of `reihe`

Comment: Why would you put `div` inside a `span`? And why would you use `align="center"`? Has nothing to do with the question, but I would suggest to write code that doesn't look like it comes from them last century.

Comment: And if you use divs as nature intended you don't need the line breaks.

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd probably have used `var mycell = $('span').eq(reihe);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `.eq()` instead.

```js
$(function() {
  var reihe = 0;
  var myCell = $('span').eq(reihe);
  console.log(myCell.attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span align="center" id="r1">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r2">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r3">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
```

Also, since each uses an ID, you could also use the ID in the selector.

```js
$(function() {
  var reihe = 1;
  var myCell = $('span[id="r' + reihe + '"]');
  console.log(myCell.attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span align="center" id="r1">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r2">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r3">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true"></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You issue *is* with the `:nth-child` (but not in the syntax).

Given the HTML provided, your 3x spans are

```
:nth-child(1)
:nth-child(3)
:nth-child(5)
```

From [nth-child-selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1

So the "first" one is `:nth-child(1)`.

*However* `:nth-child(2)` is the first `<br/>`

so your "second" span is `:nth-child(3)`  and the same for (4)(br) and then (5) for the third span.

```js
var reihe = 1;
$('span:nth-child(' + reihe + ')').css("color", "red");

reihe = 3;
$('span:nth-child(' + reihe + ')').css("color", "blue");

reihe = 5;
$('span:nth-child(' + reihe + ')').css("color", "cyan");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<span align="center" id="r1">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true">x</div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true">x</div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true">x</div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r2">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true">y</div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true">y</div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true">y</div>
</span>
<br>
<span align="center" id="r3">
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true">z</div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true">z</div>
<div class="target droppable" data-droppable="true">z</div>
</span>

</div>
```

The reason you get an empty jquery object for `:nth-child(0)` is that they start at 1.

You'll also get an empty jquery object for `span:nth-child(2)` as `:nth-child(2)` is not a span.

Using `span:nth-child(2)` is the same as `$(":nth-child(2)").filter("span")`